# Create Debian File using unix-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, unix, debian

I am trying to create debian file using unix-maven-plugin in maven project but some dependencies issues which are not to be resolve by myself. I am using

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>unix-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.0-alpha-5</version>
```

the issues was  1.0-alpha-5 is not found on local repository as well as central repository .

Let me known if there is some solution which solves my problem
 Thanks